# How do I rename address alias in Tezos?

Tags: tezos-client

I have created an account with `./tezos-client gen keys my-address`. Now I want to rename the alias of the address from `my-address` to `address1`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if a simple command exists for renaming aliases. What you can do is going to the folder of the client (usually cd ~/.tezos-client) and then rename the respective keys in the following files:

- public_key_hashs
- public_keys
- secret_keys

Comment: that's right. I also did not find any special command for that. Just edit those files and you will be fine. Do not forget to check if json still valid after editing